# Combine rows & columns in dataframes

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

Admittedly, I'm new to R, but I've managed to take a large dataset and extract the data I want and put it into a dataframe using plyr.  I'm stuck trying to combine (and count) duplicate rows and columns.

As an example, I have...

```
> df
   X x.APPLES x.BANANAS x.PEARS x.ORANGES x.GRAPES x.KIWIS x.APPLES.1 x.ORANGES.1
1  A   APPLES                                                                    
2  B   APPLES                                                                    
3  C   APPLES                                                                    
4  D            BANANAS                                                          
5  E            BANANAS                                                          
6  F            BANANAS                                                          
7  G            BANANAS                                                          
8  H                      PEARS   ORANGES   GRAPES                               
9  I                      PEARS   ORANGES   GRAPES                               
10 C                      PEARS   ORANGES   GRAPES                               
11 C                      PEARS   ORANGES   GRAPES                               
12 R                      PEARS   ORANGES   GRAPES                               
13 A                                                 KIWIS                       
14 B                                                           APPLES            
15 Y                                                           APPLES            
16 A                                                                      ORANGES
17 J                                                                      ORANGES
```

and I want...

```
       X   x.APPLES   x.BANANAS   x.PEARS   x.ORANGES   x.GRAPES   x.KIWIS COUNT
1      A APPLES (1)                       ORANGES (1)            KIWIS (1)     3
2      B APPLES (2)                                                            2
3      C APPLES (1)             PEARS (1) ORANGES (2) GRAPES (2)               3
4      D            BANANAS (1)                                                1
5      E            BANANAS (1)                                                1
6      F            BANANAS (1)                                                1
7      G            BANANAS (1)                                                1
8      H                        PEARS (1) ORANGES (1) GRAPES (1)               1
9      I                        PEARS (1) ORANGES (1) GRAPES (1)               1
10     R                        PEARS (1) ORANGES (1) GRAPES (1)               1
11     Y APPLES (1)                                                            1
12     J                                  ORANGES (1)                          1
13 COUNT          5           4        4            7          5         1    NA
```

Here's my actual code:

```
library("jsonlite")
library("plyr")
anom <- fromJSON("https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=_exists_:seriousnesscongenitalanomali&limit=25")
reactions <- anom$results$patient$reaction
drugs <- llply(anom$results$patient$drug, function(x) x$medicinalproduct)
l <- mapply(c, reactions, drugs, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
df <- ldply (l, data.frame)
```

Comment: This looks like a really odd and complex data format to work with. What does your original large dataset look like? A tall two-column (`X` and `fruit`) data.frame would be easier to work with.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to get to this point? What have you tried? It would be much easier to you help you if you made your question your reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys.  I've updated the question to show how I manipulated my actual data to get here.  The tall, two column approach seems like a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit Using OP Data:

I downloaded your actual data, and converted the data two a two-column data.frame that you can use the example below to convert to your desired output.

```
require(jsonlite)
anom <- fromJSON("https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=_exists_:seriousnesscongenitalanomali&limit=5")

## Extract the reactions and drugs as character vectors
reactions <- lapply(anom$results$patient$reaction, 
                    function(x) as.character(unlist(x)))
drugs <- lapply(anom$results$patient$drug, 
                function(x) as.character(unlist(x$medicinalproduct)))

## Use expand.grid to make subset data.frames with all drug/reaction
## combinations for every patient
l <- mapply(expand.grid, reactions, drugs, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

## Collapse all the subset data.frames into one
two_col <- do.call(rbind, l)
```

### Original Example:

If we assume you have a two-column data.frame to start:

```
require(reshape2)
fruits <- c("Bannana", "Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Kiwi")
example <- data.frame(ID = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 25, replace = TRUE),
                      Fruit = sample(fruits, 25, replace = TRUE))

# > example
#    ID   Fruit
# 1   F    Kiwi
# 2   A   Apple
# 3   F    Kiwi
# ...

dcast(example, ID~Fruit, length, value.var = "Fruit")

more_complex <- function(x) {
  x_len <- length(x)
  x <- paste0(unique(x), " (", x_len, ")")
  x
}

dcast(example, ID~Fruit, more_complex, value.var = "Fruit")

# > dcast(example, ID~Fruit, more_complex, value.var = "Fruit")
#   ID     Apple     Bannana     Grape     Kiwi     Orange
# 1  A Apple (2) Bannana (2) Grape (2)      (0) Orange (2)
# 2  B Apple (1)         (0)       (0) Kiwi (1) Orange (2)
# 3  C       (0) Bannana (2)       (0) Kiwi (1) Orange (1)
# 4  D       (0) Bannana (1)       (0)      (0) Orange (1)
# 5  E       (0)         (0) Grape (1) Kiwi (1)        (0)
# 6  F       (0) Bannana (1) Grape (1) Kiwi (2) Orange (1)

another_option <- function(x) {
  x_len <- length(x)
  if (x_len == 0) return(NA_character_)
  x <- paste0(unique(x), " (", x_len, ")")
  x
}

dcast(example, ID~Fruit, another_option, value.var = "Fruit")

# > dcast(example, ID~Fruit, another_option, value.var = "Fruit")
#   ID     Apple     Bannana     Grape     Kiwi     Orange
# 1  A Apple (2) Bannana (2) Grape (2)     <NA> Orange (2)
# 2  B Apple (1)        <NA>      <NA> Kiwi (1) Orange (2)
# 3  C      <NA> Bannana (2)      <NA> Kiwi (1) Orange (1)
# 4  D      <NA> Bannana (1)      <NA>     <NA> Orange (1)
# 5  E      <NA>        <NA> Grape (1) Kiwi (1)       <NA>
# 6  F      <NA> Bannana (1) Grape (1) Kiwi (2) Orange (1)
```